# Debian package very large compared to zip file

Tags: debian, dpkg

I've just made a debian package, when all the files are zipped together the size is `60 MB`, however my `.deb` file made from the same directory is `~150 MB`. Have I done something wrong or are there lots of overheads involved with `.deb` files, and if so would it be possible to get a brief run-down of what is added to the raw files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.deb` file is an `ar` archive with typically those files:

```
$ ar tv apache2_2.4.6-2_amd64.deb
rw-r--r-- 0/0      4 Jul 23 12:51 2013 debian-binary
rw-r--r-- 0/0   7422 Jul 23 12:51 2013 control.tar.gz
rw-r--r-- 0/0 179960 Jul 23 12:51 2013 data.tar.xz
```

(the used compression can be `gz`, `bz2` or `xz`).

The `ar` archive is not compressed itself, only the components are.

Only `data.tar.xxx` should be significantly large as it contains the actual files that make up the package.

You can check the content with:

```
$ ar p apache2_2.4.6-2_amd64.deb data.tar.xz | tar --xz -tvf - | head
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-23 12:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-23 12:47 ./var/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-23 12:47 ./var/cache/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-23 12:47 ./var/cache/apache2/
drwxr-xr-x www-data/www-data 0 2013-07-23 12:47 ./var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-23 12:47 ./var/www/
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful. I think the reason my file is getting so large is because it's including a huge .git file! I'm going to have to research how to exclude these directories from packages.

Comment: On a Debian (Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) system, you can list the content with `dpkg-deb -c foo.deb`.

Comment: @Gilles, yes, though it may not help you find out problems with the size of your `deb` file as it only lists the content of the `data.tar`, not the other components of the `ar` archive, or the type of compression used for `data.tar`, or if there may be additional unwanted files in the `ar` archive. In this case though it would have helped find the source of the problem though.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The way a `.deb` file is normally generated, the ar archive will only contain the three files it's meant to contain, and the `control` archive will only contain a few files that are supposed to be text files. Only the `data` archive has arbitrary directories added to it in the normal course of things.